# How to use sorting in pandas with similar names?

Tags: pandas

I have used **.sort_values(by = ['Tag'])** it gets the work done but it doesn't sort based on the index and when I used **.sort_index** it works but again the **tag** gets **jumbled**. Any heads up, please.

| Index | Tag |
| --- | --- |
| 1294 | P3010A |
| 1638 | P3010B |
| 1122 | P3010A |
| 1466 | P3010A |
| 950 | P3010B |
| 99 | P3010A |
| 434 | P3010A |
| 262 | P3010B |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this?

```
>>> df.sort_values(['Tag','Index'])
   Index     Tag
5     99  P3010A
6    434  P3010A
2   1122  P3010A
0   1294  P3010A
3   1466  P3010A
7    262  P3010B
4    950  P3010B
1   1638  P3010B
```

Comment: It's not working it sorts the index and it sorts the tag in such a way that after P3010A you get P3010B

Comment: got it at last, Thank You